# How can I solve this no such file log error in Kafka quickstart?

Tags: logging, apache-kafka

I'm following (at least trying to) this Kafka quickstart doc [Kafka quickstart](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart)

Upon executing the Kafka and Zookeeper server starts, they both result in this error:

```
[0.003s][error][logging] Error opening log file '/c/Users/Manol/Downloads/kafka_2.13-2.7.0/kafka_2.13-2.7.0/bin/../logs/kafkaServer-gc.log': No such file or directory

[0.003s][error][logging] Error opening log file '/c/Users/Manol/downloads/kafka_2.13-2.7.0/kafka_2.13-2.7.0/bin/../logs/zookeeper-gc.log': No such file or directory
```

I've even tried manually creating these files to confirm they are actually there:

[image]

But it made no difference.
I have not a single clue of what could cause this error and I'm also not familiar with .sh files so I can't see if there's any problems in those.
Does anyone know what could be the problem and maybe even how to fix it? I couldn't find anyone else experiencing this particular issue.

Comment: Use WSL2, not git shell / cygwin https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/

Answer (score 7):

You may get this error, when you try to start Zookeper or Kafka in git-shell or cygwin.

A potential solution is to start Zookeeper and Kafka in [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

After adding WSL support in Windows, you could [install a Linux distribution like Ubuntu](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6?activetab=pivot:overviewtab).

Zookeper and Kafka started like a charm on Ubuntu running in WSL:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[Kafka quickstart](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart) is intended to use `.sh` scripts, for windows use `.bat` scripts.

Here is how I fixed the issue, run following command.

```
$ bin/windows/zookeeper-server-start.bat config/zookeeper.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the Java version to 8 solved the problem for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me I got this issue resolved by changing the JAVA_HOME to "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_341/bin/java", means explicitly set the JAVA_HOME. The version should be JDK1.8. I tried with version JDK18.0.2, which is not working.
Hope it helps for the starters. Cheers!!!